# Uniqueness of variational heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

> $u_{t} - u_{xx} + cu = f $ on $U_{T}$
>
> $u = g$ on $\Gamma_{T}$

Problem is Show uniqueness of solution. I tried to find it with energy method, but the method doesn't working since $\frac{\partial }{\partial t}e(t) = 2\int_{U}ww_{t} + w^{2} dx = -\int_{U}|Dw|^{2}dx+e(t)$ Could you give me a hint?

Edited; **Proof :** Just let $v(x,t) = e^{ct}u(x,t)$ then I can use energy method since $v(x,t)$ solves non homogeneous heat equation, which I can deal with!

Comment: What are $U_T$ and $\Gamma_T$?

Comment: @Paul Just $U_{T} = \mathbb{R}^{n}\times (0,T)$, $\Gamma_{T} = \mathbb{R}^{n}\times (t=0)$. I think I prove it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method works fine.  Here's another idea:

Suppose that $u_1$ and $u_2$ are two solutions to the variational heat equation as given.  It follows that $v := u_1-u_2$ satisfies

> $v_{t} - v_{xx} + cv = 0 $ on $U_{T}$
>
> $v = 0$ on $\Gamma_{T}$

(Why is this the case?).  It follows that $v(x,t) = 0$ (why is this the case)?  That is, $u_1(x,t) - u_2(x,t) = 0$, which is to say that $u_1$ and $u_2$ are identical solutions.  We conclude that the solution to this IVP is unique.

Comment: Actually I know answer of first question, but not second question. Why v(x,t) =0?

Comment: Does the energy method not work for $v$?  If not, I guess you could  just note that $e^{ct}v(x,t)$ solves the heat equation to come to the same conclusion.